# How should I design this database?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate

Let's say I have 10 millions of product names, e.g. iPhone 6. For each product name, there may be multiple comments or reviews. When users search for a product name, it will display all comments for it. Should I use two tables to fulfill this requirement?

Table one: ProductName, with only one column, "prodName"
Table two: Comments, with only one column, "comments"

What's the relationship between the two? I am new to database design, and will use MySql to do this, Hibernate in Java. I am thinking to make it as simple as possible, to start with.

Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: 10 million products, and you want to keep it simple?  That's a mistake.  Design right the first time.  To that end, you should only have information in each table once.  Nothing repeated except the IDs that join tables together.

Comment: Maybe you could think about migrating to a *big data* architecture, e.g. with a NoSQL database such as MongoDB.

Comment: Just do something simple, however fast and effective: map the `product_id` to the comment table, so your product can have as many comments you want, but will the related to one product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were to keep a single table for product information and comments for that product you would need to duplicate the product name for each comment made. When having to store 10 million products that can be very dangerous.

Another issue is table extensibility. Lets say you want to add another info, apart from the name, that is closely linked to the product i.e. stock. You do not want to have that info in your table duplicated based on the comments being made for that product.

To avoid these kind of issues you could consider an architecture similar to this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b50a8/2, link your tables with their keys and avoid information duplication.

Comment: SQLFiddle, that's awesome! Great suggestion as well!

Comment: What about use one table to keep 10 millions product names, and use 10 millions tables to keep comments for each product? Does this offer better performance compared to two-table design?

Comment: @martin, it provides actually a worse solution. Why would you have duplicated information in your database for no reason ?

Comment: Thank you. I thought each comment table for each product is much smaller than a huge comment table. That might be more efficient in lookup.

Comment: @martin Think about it like so: every table requires some memory overhead to store its definition (the type of data that it stores, column names, the character encoding etc.). That normally isn't something that you should worry about: you can have hundreds of tables in a schema and your server won't sweat it. What you suggest though is to have that overhead for every comment instance; essentially each table's overhead will be larger than the content it stores! That's definitely not a good idea! The lookup inefficiency is true but a secondary issue.